# Use hook_menu_alter to override page callback of web form module

Tags: drupal, hook-menu

I wanted to modify the menu settings of the webform module by writing a own module. While i achieved what I wanted by hacking into the code of webform, I could not make this going by writing my own module.

My Goal is to override webform 4 in a way, that specific users can access to the analysis page provided by the module, without giving them access to the all results.

Taken from webform_menu() of the contrib module

```
  $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results'] = array(
    'title' => 'Results',
    'page callback' => 'webform_results_submissions',
    'page arguments' => array(1, FALSE, '50'),
    'access callback' => 'webform_results_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'file' => 'includes/webform.report.inc',
    'weight' => 2,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
  );
  $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results/submissions'] = array(
    'title' => 'Submissions',
    'page callback' => 'webform_results_submissions',
    'page arguments' => array(1, FALSE, '50'),
    'access callback' => 'webform_results_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'file' => 'includes/webform.report.inc',
    'weight' => 4,
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
  $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results/analysis'] = array(
    'title' => 'Analysis',
    'page callback' => 'webform_results_analysis',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'webform_results_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'file' => 'includes/webform.report.inc',
    'weight' => 5,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
```

The code of my module is:

```
<?php
function webformanalysis_permission() {
  return array(
    'access all webform results analysis' => array(
      'title' => t('Access all webform results Analysis'),
      'description' => t('Grants access to the "Analysis" tab on all webform content.'),
    ),
  );
}

function webformanalysis_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results']['access arguments'] = array('access all webform results analysis');
    $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results']['page callback'] = 'webform_results_analysis';
    $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results']['page arguments'] = array(1);
    unset($items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results']['access callback']);

    $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results/analysis']['access arguments'] = array('access all webform results analysis');
    $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results/analysis']['type'] = 'MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK';
    unset($items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results/analysis']['access callback']);

    $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results/submissions']['type'] = 'MENU_LOCAL_TASK';
}
```

But the code is not doing anything. Of cause I cleared the cache.
What is going wrong. Even the "page callback" of the "webform-results" page does not change.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a *var_dump* or similar at the end of your HOOK_menu_alter() implementation and check if you see the changes correctly

Comment: Thank you. I get 7 times the whole menu array every time I go on the webpage (I thought the hook is called only once when I clear the menu chache).
And the changes are applied.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after hours of testing and playing around, I found my mistake. I defined the type as a String, but it seems to be a Constant. Oh my God!